# A noncommutative vector bundle

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, hochschild-cohomology

We know that a  noncommutative vector bundle is a  finitely generated projective $A$-module where $A$ is a non commutative $C^{*}$ algebra. In this  question we introduce  a particular non commutative $C^{*}$ algebra $A$ and a particular $A$- bimodule $M$, see **Construction** below. Then our question would be :

> Is this particular $M$ a finitely generated projective $A$-module ?
>
> If the answer is yes, how can we compute non commutative characteristic classes of such non commutative vector bundle?

**Construction:**

Let $N$ be  a  compact smooth  Riemannian manifold. By $\lambda^{p}(N)$ we mean the  space of all smooth complex valued $(0,p)$ tensors on $M$. Our pre $C^{*}$ algebra is $A=\lambda^{*}(N)=\oplus \lambda^{p}(N)$ which multiplication is the tensor product.  We can equip $A$ to  a  pre-$C^{*}$ algebra structure as follows:
 If $\alpha \in \lambda^{p}(N)$, we define $\parallel \alpha \parallel= \sup \parallel \alpha_{x}\parallel ,\;\;x\in N$. The  later norm is the standard "multilinear norm" for $p$-linear maps on the tangent space $T_{x} N$.Then we take the sup-norm to  define  a norm on $\lambda^{*}(N)$ as  a  graded algebra. (Note that when we restrict $A$ and $M$ to $T_{x} N$, that is we consider a linear problem, we obtain an $AF$ algebra,"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximately_finite-dimensional_C*-algebra". What is the K groups  of this $AF$ algebra?)

Our module $M$ is $M=\Omega^{*}(N)$, the space of differential forms. Now we define the  scalar product as follows:

In a  local coordinate $\lambda \in A$  and $\alpha \in M$  are  a sum of the following objects:

$\lambda=dx_{i_{1}}\otimes \ldots \otimes dx_{i{k}}\;\;\;   \alpha=dx_{j_{1}} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_{j_{l}}$  we define $\lambda.\alpha=dx_{i_{1}}\wedge \ldots \wedge dx_{i{k}} \wedge dx_{j_{1}} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_{j_{l}}$

This  is  independent of  choosing  a particular local coordinate.

> Are there some geometric or topological information of M in the cohomology of $A$ with coefficient in $M$?

Comment: So, is the question as follows: *Is any module over a noncommutative $C^*$ algebra a finitely generated projective module over the noncommutative $C^*$ algebra?*

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar My question is not this. I do not underestand why you think this is equivalent to my question?could you please more explain?

Comment: You asked «Is M a finitely generated projective A-module?» but you did not impose any conditions on the module... Are you asking how can one recognize a f.g. projective module or what, exactly?

Comment: What follows the subtitle «construction» does not have any obvious connection with what precedes it...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I add a few words to my question. Now is it clear?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Is this new version clear, now?

Comment: sorry if the previous version was not clear.

Comment: Sorry I am still not sure I understand you correctly. What is an $AF$ algebra? When $N$ is a point, the tangent space is trivial, so $A$ must be just complex numbers, no? Is your $M$ the quotient of $A$ by the one-sided or two-sided ideal generated by elements $dx_i\otimes dx_i$ and $dx_i\otimes dx_j+dx_j\otimes dx_i$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე thank you for your comment. By AF algebra I mean approximately finite dimension C* algebra. As for "N Is a point' you are right. It was not a good terminology but I realy meant "We restrict ourselves to $T_{x} N$,where $x$ is a point in N.That is we consider such construction for a single n dim. linear space (not a bundle of linear space. As your last statement, are you considering the manifold case or a single n. di linear space?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  In linear 3 dim.case there is a natural module morphism from A to M. $dx \otimes dy \otimes dx is inthe kernel of such morphism but I guess it is not in the ideal which you mentioned.

Comment: So, maybe I'm wrong, but your algebra $A$ looks pretty much like Toeplitz algebra for the algebra of continuous functions on $N$. I don't remember how to calculate K-groups of Toeplitz algebra, possibly they are trivial, you should better google it.